# Fitting images together and animate images in on window load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically, I'm trying to get the images to fit in as much as possible but I haven't been able to do it.  I downloaded masonry but it doesn't seem to work for me.  I just want to pack the div's together.  For example, in my fiddle, I want the bottom left and right cat to go up.

Also, I'm looking to get it to animate in when the user views it the first time on page load, like this:
http://flipgallery.net/#demo

Any ideas how to do either?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/0jL2dyg1/

```css
.grid{
display:flex;
flex-direction:row;
justify-content:center;
max-width:500px;
flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.grid-item{
  height:150px;
  width:150px;
  overflow:hidden;

}
.grid-item img{
  height:100%;
}
.item-2{
  height:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item"><img src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg"></div>
  <div class="grid-item item-2"><img src="http://www.joomlaworks.net/images/demos/galleries/abstract/7.jpg"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"><img src="http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"><img src="http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"><img src="http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png"></div>
      <div class="grid-item"><img src="http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any reason the longer picture has a `item-2` class? Do you want them to all have the same classes?

Comment: your image are not on same scale, so if you want to fit them together ,best option is "masonry" or other plugin like that. one question, do this important for you to show all of your image?can your image be scale or crop?

Comment: @Samir no, I want some to be a differene length and width, much like: http://www.webdesign-flash.ro/p/ugp/index.html

Comment: @shayanypn it's not important that the whole image is shown, it can be cropped as long as the div's fit together nicely

Answer (score 0):

you could try this.masonory example

```
<style type="text/css">
.grid {
  max-width:500px;
}
.grid:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.grid-item{
  height:100px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.grid-sizer{
  width: 100px;
}
.item-2{
  height:200px;
}
.item-3{
  width: 300px;
}
.item-4{
  width: 400px;
}
.grid-item img{
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
<div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"><img src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg"></div>
    <div class="grid-item item-2"><img src="http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"><img src="http://www.joomlaworks.net/images/demos/galleries/abstract/7.jpg"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"><img src="http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"><img src="http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"><img src="http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png"></div>
    <div class="grid-item item-3"><img src="http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png"></div>
    <div class="grid-item item-4"><img src="http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"><img src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"><img src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"><img src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.grid').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
}).masonry("layout");
</script>
```

Comment: @Snorlax i change my answer codes, try that. it's fine and ok for me. with no problem

Answer (score 0):

This is from [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/), but I used your images

HTML

```
<section id="photos">
  <img src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg">
  <img src="http://www.joomlaworks.net/images/demos/galleries/abstract/7.jpg">
  <img src="http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png">
  <img src="http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png">
  <img src="http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png">
  <img src="http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png">
</section>
```

CSS

```
#photos {
  /* Prevent vertical gaps */
  line-height: 0;

  -webkit-column-count: 5;
  -webkit-column-gap:   0px;
  -moz-column-count:    5;
  -moz-column-gap:      0px;
  column-count:         5;
  column-gap:           0px;  
}

#photos img {
  /* Just in case there are inline attributes */
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  #photos {
  -moz-column-count:    4;
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  column-count:         4;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  #photos {
  -moz-column-count:    3;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  column-count:         3;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #photos {
  -moz-column-count:    2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  column-count:         2;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  #photos {
  -moz-column-count:    1;
  -webkit-column-count: 1;
  column-count:         1;
  }
}
```

Is this what you were looking for? [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/6o2e7fg7/) is a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

1- remove `item-2` class.

2- add `margin-bottom` and `margin-left` properties to `grid-item` class:

```
.grid-item{
  height:150px;
  width:150px;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

Check out this [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/0jL2dyg1/1/).